# how to run java lambda function in aws

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc

try{
            PreparedStatement pst=con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO employee_details (E_NAME,E_PASSWORD,E_USERNAME,E_CONTACT,"
                    + "E_ROLE) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?);");
            state=1;

```
        pst.setString(1,employee.getEname());//Step 7: calling getter() from getter/setter class
    //Step 10: setting getter values to corresponding query
        pst.setString(2,employee.getPass());//Step 7: calling getter() from getter/setter class
            //Step 10: setting getter values to corresponding
        pst.setString(3,employee.getUname());//Step 7: calling getter() from getter/setter class
            //Step 10: setting getter values to corresponding 
        pst.setString(4,employee.getEcontact());//Step 7: calling getter() from getter/setter class
            //Step 10: setting getter values to corresponding 
        pst.setInt(5,employee.getUrole());//Step 7: calling getter() from getter/setter class
            //Step 10: setting getter values to corresponding 
        pst.executeQuery();
        System.out.println("name:"+employee.getEname()+"  pass:"+employee.getPass()+"   uname:"+employee.getUname()+"  con:"+employee.getEcontact()+"  role:"+employee.getUrole());

    }
    catch(SQLException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: not much to to go on.  What does your table look like?  What data were you trying to insert?

Comment: might want to move the println to the first line of the try to see if your data is bad

Comment: Refer Java Doc http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an unwanted semi-colon at the end of your prepare statement so remove it.

Try this

```
 PreparedStatement pst=con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO employee_details (E_NAME,E_PASSWORD,E_USERNAME,E_CONTACT,"
                + "E_ROLE) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)");
```

instead of

```
 PreparedStatement pst=con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO employee_details (E_NAME,E_PASSWORD,E_USERNAME,E_CONTACT,"
                + "E_ROLE) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?);");
```